# Why doesn't this simple search work?

Tags: python

am simply iterating through an external file (which contains a phrase) and want to see if a line exists (which has the word 'Dad' in it) If i find it, I want to replace it with 'Mum'. Here is the program i've built... but am not sure why it isn't working?!

```
message_file = open('test.txt','w')
message_file.write('Where\n')
message_file.write('is\n')
message_file.write('Dad\n')
message_file.close()

message_temp_file = open('testTEMP.txt','w')
message_file = open('test.txt','r')

for line in message_file:
    if line == 'Dad':  # look for the word
        message_temp_file.write('Mum')  # replace it with mum in temp file
    else:
        message_temp_file.write(line)  # else, just write the word

message_file.close()
message_temp_file.close()

import os
os.remove('test.txt')
os.rename('testTEMP.txt','test.txt')
```

This should be so simple...it's annoyed me!  Thanks.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by *... it isn't working?*

Comment: Your edits are affecting the given answers now. You should explain your edits so that future readers understand the context of answers based on previous editions of your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have any lines that are `"Dad"`. You have a line that is `"Dad\n"`, but no `"Dad"`. In addition, since you've done `message_file.read()`, the cursor is at the end of your file so `for line in message_file` will return `StopIteration` immediately. You should do `message_file.seek(0)` just before your `for` loop.

```
print(message_file.read())
message_file.seek(0)
for line in message_file:
    if line.strip() == "Dad":
        ...
```

That should put the cursor back at the beginning of the file, and strip out the newline and get you what you need.

Note that this exercise is a great example of how not to do things in general! The better implementation would have been:

```
in_ = message_file.read()
out = in_.replace("Dad","Mum")
message_temp_file.write(out)
```

Comment: @user3396486 glad to hear it! If my answer helped you come to a solution, please consider [accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: The "better implementation" gets complicated if you handle very big files because you temporarily store the whole file in the variable `in_`. In this case it would be saver to stick to the `for` loop, since it only stores one line at a time

Comment: @MaSp agreed, but since this file is already being read into memory from his first call of `.read()`, I couldn't imagine it being an issue to keep it in memory ;). Honestly the better implementation would use `str.replace` (or `re.replace`) while iterating through lines, but it's more work and for a file this trivially small, it's more complicated too.

Answer (score 3):

```
print(message_file.read())
```

here you already read the whole file.
Nothing is left for the for loop to check

A file object always remembers where it stopped to read/write the last time you accessed it.
So if you call  `print(message_file.readline())`, the first line of the file is read and printed. Next time you call the same command, the second line is read and printed and so on until you reach the end of the file. By using `print(message_file.read())` you have read the whole file and any further call of `read` or `readline` will give you nothing

You can get the current position by `message_file.tell()` and set it to a certain value by `message_file.seek(value)`, or simply reopen the file

Comment: `message_file.read()` reads the whole file until it discovers the EOF (EndOfFile)
`message_file.readline()`would read the file line by line. This is what happens in each turn of the for construct. It reads a line from the file and hands it into the loop under the name line. A file object contains the position from where to read in the file. So if you read a line, the file object has changed. If you read the whole file. The pointer is at the and of the file and every attempt to read s.th. will simply give nothing

Comment: I mean you should explain by editing the answer, not in comments. :P

Comment: Sure, I will copy it;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem most likely is due to the fact that your conditional will only match the string "Dad", when the string is actually "Dad\n".  You could either update your conditional to:

```
if line == "Dad\n":
```

OR

```
if "Dad" in line:
```

Lastly, you also read the entire file when you call print(message_file.read()).  You either need to remove that line, or you need to put a call to message_file.seek(0) in order for the loop that follows to actually do anything.